# Develop hierarchy query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the scenario shown on the List below so that you can understand my question more clearly.

I want to develop a spinning cursor that will enable me to find the top leader of any agent in the bottom of the pyramid  in the organization.

Consider as if the only information you have is each person's immediate upline shown in the list below. Can you help me to develop a query that retrieves the top leader's name and staff_id of each agent using a sql cursor?

Then I will try to develop a cursor for my company which has a similar organization of staffs but more complex. Using only cursor or looping query is highly appreciated.

```
Staff_id Name    Title               Upline      Upline_id
-------- ------- ------------------- ----------- ---------
1        Peter   Agent               Fred        10
2        Paul    Agent               Fred        10
3        Michael Agent               Fred        10
4        George  Agent               Rick        11
5        Will    Agent               Rick        11
6        Jeff    Agent               Rick        11
7        Mark    Agent               Deon        12
8        Alberto Agent               Deon        12
9        Charles Agent               Deon        12
10       Fred    Leader              Aaron       13
11       Rick    Leader              Zack        14
12       Deon    Leader              Brown       15
13       Aaron   General Manager     Milton      16
14       Zack    General Manager     Nancy       17
15       Brown   General Manager     Nick        18
16       Milton  District Manager    Ken         19
17       Nancy   District Manager    Miller      20
18       Nick    District Manager    Tad         21
19       Ken     Top Leader          Null        Null
20       Miller  Top Leader          Null        Null
21       Tad     Top Leader          Null        Null
```

Comment: Why are you set on doing this with a cursor?, why can't you use a recursive CTE?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a reporting hierarchy. Your specification of using a SQL Cursor and tagging with SSRS, SSIS and SSAS leads me to believe you are constraining yourself to a solution without fully understanding your problem.

Comment: I am new to recursive CTE. Can you give me your solution?

Comment: I totally understood the problem and I also created a chart that shows the organization chart but I can't post pictures since I am new to stackoverflow and I don't have reputations. Thank you for editing the list billinkc.

Comment: @ddag Is that really the table structure?, I mean, do you have the *name* of the immediate superior instead of the `id`?, why?

Comment: Yes it is a table structure but created on excel and it has four field. The staff_id, name, title and immediate supervisor. I edited it in table format but it is not showing up.

Comment: But why are you choosing to use the name of the supervisor instead if the staff_id?

Comment: That sounds better. I will also add that field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a hierarchy like this as Lamak pointed out a recursive CTE is the best way to go.

```
WITH subordinates AS
(
SELECT     mt.name, mt.upline, mt.title
FROM       myTable mt
WHERE      Staff_id = 11

UNION ALL

SELECT     mt2.name, mt2.upline, mt2.title
FROM       subordinates  s
INNER JOIN myTable mt2
  ON       mt2.upline = s.name
)

SELECT    s.name, s.upline, s.title
FROM      subordinates
```

This query will get all of Rick's subordinates.

However, as you can see I'm having to join onto the names whereas the upline column should actually contain the id of the staff member rather than then name. This would avoid the problem of a persons name existing twice which would shew the hierarchy.